Bluetooth mouse not being detected on ubuntu 22.04, lenovo silent. dual booted with windows 11. please help, im not good with linux
I have a Lenovo silent bluetooth mouse. It was not getting connected so i unpaired it and ever since it never got detected again by my system, i have currently unpaired it fromt he windows partition.
Im not so good with linux, please ask for any additional info if needed n ill post it in minutes

Is it in pairing mode when you try to detect?

Did you turn off hibernation in windows?

Can Windows detect the mouse among available bluetooth devices?

Check the battery in the mouse too.
